# using value of a variable rather than the variable name to assign to in R in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

After hours of googling and trying, I'm still stuck... so hopefully someone can help out. I'm still beginner at R, and pretty sure there is a simple answer to this.
I have the following code:

```
gamenumber <- 0
for(i in 1:9) {
  gamenumber <- paste("game201702000", toString(i), sep = "")
  gamelinknumber <- paste("201702000", toString(i), sep = "")
  gamelink <- paste("http://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/",gamelinknumber,"/feed/live", sep="")

  gamenumber <- fromJSON(gamelink)
}
```

My intent is that I go through the loop, creating a new gamenumber and gamelink every time, and write the content of the link page to the gamenumber. However, R writes to content from the gamelink to "gamenumber", rather than the value gamenumber is representing.

I want to end up with:
VALUES panel in Rstudio

- game2017020001 Large list (6 elements, 1.1 Mb)
- game2017020002 Large list (6 elements, 1.1 Mb)
- game2017020003 Large list (6 elements, 1.1 Mb)
- ...
- game2017020009 Large list (6 elements, 1.1 Mb)

but I end up with:

- gamenumber Large list (6 elements, 1.1 Mb)

I have tried get, paste, and other things I found and thought were the solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What you want to do is possible but not recommended. You'll have a better time creating a single list that has all game data in it. so you can call them as game$2017020003. Is there a reason why you want them as separate objects?

Comment: Only because I would not know how to do what you suggest. In the end I would write out these individual files as csv and join them in a data base, so if that would be a fairly simple thing to do, please elaborate?  I found the following: lpos
[1] 5

for(i in 1:lpos){
indx <- sapply(example[,4], function(x) (x > minpos[i]) & (x < maxpos[i])) 
newrow <- example[indx,]
result = rbind(result, newrow)
}

Comment: before loop, create empty list as `game = list()`. Within the loop assign your results to the list by `game[[gameNumber]] =  fromJSON(gamelink)`. This results in a single `game` list for you to loop around. If you loop with `i in 1:length(game)`, you can save your files by calling `game[[i]]` and setting the file name to `names(game)[i]`

Comment: That's awesome OganM, thank you for your suggestion and quick help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use `assign()`

```
for(i in 1:9) {
  gamenumber <- paste("game201702000", toString(i), sep = "")
  gamelinknumber <- paste("201702000", toString(i), sep = "")
  gamelink <- paste("http://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/", gamelinknumber, "/feed/live", sep="")

  assign(gamenumber, fromJSON(gamelink))
}
```

Comment: Great! thank you Lucy. I had tried Assign, but not in the correct format.